# Is there a way to prevent corpses from disappearing?

Tags: fallout-4

I have a bunch of dead bodies in Covenant which I'd like to decorate the town with. Also I thought of maybe collecting some Glowing One corpses to use as electricity-free light source.

I'd like to know if they despawn in town, and if so how I can prevent that. If it can't be done without cheating can I use some sort of console command?

Comment: +1 cause I want to decorate Covenant with dead bodies now as well!

Comment: -1 (jk, not really) I want to *make* corpses disappear, not keep them around. And don't say "console" 'cause I'm on one.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The only experience i've had was picking up a decapitated head and trying to move it up a hill, the head would freeze in place as if an invisible wall was holding it back as I tried to move it all the way up. I'm not sure if that is because it has to be within X distance of the body or what, but maybe try to carry the body from place to place (hold "Use" to pick things up) and see what happens. I bet it's a memory thing and the body will disappear eventually when you're not looking.

Comment: @Iszi the method of choice is either cannibalism or dumping into a flowing river. And if your settlement doesn't have one, then cry me one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the PC version there's a mod called [Piles of Corpses](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/1770/?).

According to the modder Fallout 4's/the mod's (not explicitly stated which one) default values are:

> ---iHoursToClearCorpses - 24 [1 day] (Resets when you return to the cell)
>   ---iRemoveExcessDeadComplexCount - 3
>   ---iRemoveExcessDeadCount - 15
>   ---iRemoveExcessDeadComplexTotalActorCount - 20
>   ---iRemoveExcessDeadTotalActorCount - 20

After installing the mod you can edit based on your preferences. **Be sure to take backups of your save files before using mods**.

Fallout 4 engine maybe limited to 1000 bodies as the modder uses "999 supermutants and a piper" in the demonstration screenshot:

[image: Piles of Corpses screenshot]

Comment: That 1000 corpses would crash my system.  The only problem you would have decorating with corpses would be making them stay in place and in a position you want like placing them on a wall and they keep falling off.

Answer (score 2):

As per @Nelson, if we assume things work the same as in Skyrim, then an area should reset in 3-30 days, depending on some variables. **So, if you visit at least every three days, the corpses should stay.**

I had a playthrough where I used the Red Rocket Truck Stop as my main settlement, and the molerats from the initial encounter there remained for the entire game. That character never got local leader, so I'm sure I visited the truck stop at least every three days.

Comment: any hard numbers?

Comment: Tried sleeping 3 days straight, corpses still there. With flies. Dunno. Those molerats stayed at red rocket for me for a long time as well, but they're no longer there. Wish I knew what day you start the game at.

Comment: If we can use Skyrim's system as a baseline, the upper limit would be 30 days.  However, not all places require 30 days to reset, and some will require as little as 3.

Comment: @Nelson Thanks. I'll assume that it's the same for now.

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC There are some more specific numbers.

Comment: Something tells me I'm going to spend more time experimenting than playing.

Comment: I just found the head of nelson latimer where i left it, on top of his cargo boxes. I most definitely haven't been there in a long, long time. Last time I saw him I dumped his detached body in the river. What's more, his inventory respawned (with only 50 caps not 800)

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC Is a long, long time more than 30 days? I would be surprised if it took me more than 30 days to finish the game.

Comment: More than 3 days for sure. Every time I go back to home base i sleep until morning for the sunlight, but even then probably not 30 days.