# In what manner the killed enemies disappear in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-2

Enemies disappear in Witcher 2 almost instantly after being killed and leave only a bag of loot behind. I'm sure that bodies have to be removed in an open world game, how does this happen in Witcher 3?
I haven't played W3, I found disappearing corpses immersion-breaking in W2.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. Bodies also disappear leaving loot bags in Witcher 3.

Comment: @greg-449 in GTA V, bodies disappear when, quite literally, no one is looking. In PvZ:GW2, they disappear after 3 seconds. In Borderlands 2, they disintegrate, or delete when no one is looking.  In the Witcher 3, they disappear when~..?

Comment: @greg-449 That's what I'm asking, I haven't played Witcher 3.

Comment: @user598527 you mean technically, as in game programming? I still don't get it, sorry. I didn't downvote this but still think it's not really on topic, or at least not really clear enough.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: See this highly upvoted post? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246088/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-corpses-from-disapearing

Comment: This is different. The other question asks how to prevent X from happening, you ask why X is happening. Not the same thing at all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I didn't ask "WHY", I asked "HOW"!

Comment: Oops sorry. Still, same thing as we can't really know. This is a design choice by the game developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bodies do disappear leaving a loot bag.

They don't seem to go when you are looking at them but they do go if you leave the area or a large number builds up during a big fight.

Comment: The bodies don't instantly disappear as they do in Witcher 2, I haven't even yet seen any corpses going away. Are you sure that a loot back is always left behind even if you leave the area?

Comment: I'm not sure that a loot bag is always left if you leave the area, I was talking about the bodies in the answer. I generally end up with too much loot so I haven't really checked that.